# Showing json data upon selecting item from suggestion list

Tags: flutter

I want to fetch and show corresponding player's data when their name is selected from the suggestion list. I have `AutoCompleteTextField` widget using which player's name is typed and selected from the list, as below:

[image]

Current issue I am facing is, when player is searched and selected, then I get `null` value back at first, as below:

[image]

But when I tap in the search field and select the same player again from suggestion list, then the api call is made and data is shown properly, as below:

[image]

Current code is, on `itemSubmitted` parameter of `AutoCompleteTextfield`, I am making call to the method that shows the data inside `setState()`, as below:

```
itemSubmitted: (item) {
                  setState(() {
                    searchTextField.textField.controller.text = item.name;
                    textInput = true;
                    showData();
                  });
                },
```

Inside `showData()`, I am parsing the json per input search in the field and if player data is found, I am making another call inside same method to fetch the data, as below:

```
showData() {
    String input = searchTextField.textField.controller.text.toLowerCase();
    found = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < PlayerViewModel.players.length; i++) {
      if (PlayerViewModel.players[i].name.toLowerCase() == input) {
        players = PlayerViewModel.players[i];
        found = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (found) {
      fetchJson(players.pid);
    }
  }

  void fetchJson(int pid) async {
    var response = await http.get(
        'http://cricapi.com/api/playerStats?apikey=<apiKey>&pid=$pid');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      String responseBody = response.body;
      var responseJson = jsonDecode(responseBody);
      name = responseJson['name'];
      playingRole = responseJson['playingRole'];
      battingStyle = responseJson['battingStyle'];
      country = responseJson['country'];
      imageURL = responseJson['imageURL'];
      data = responseJson;
```

The data is fetched properly but not firing at first attempt when I select player from list, but only at second attempt when I select the player again from the list. And this happens for every subsequent player search.
What am I missing here ? How to fetch and show the data as soon as the player name is selected from suggestion list ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement a FutureBuilder where the future is fetchJson() which returns data. Also try to see what it returns.

```
   if (found) {
      fetchJson(players.pid).then(print);
    }
```

Comment: This returns `null` at first and subsequent attempts.

Comment: You should return "data" variable from fetchJson method. The return type shouldn't be void.

Comment: I see. returning `data` is now printing the actual data back.

Comment: you can use then like this 
.then((data){
setState(){
.....
}
})